# Fault Exception - Method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm having some trouble with references to an external project that contains services for my application.
After changing the types of some properties in a class, I got errors like "Method not found: get_Size() (Where Size is the name of the field)

After rebuilding numerous times, deleting the class and adding a new one with a different name, I'm faced with a new but similar problem.  Now the application can't find a method that is in my Factory class:

Method not found: 'Ropes.Services.Contracts.Data.SearchResultPage`1 Ropes.Services.Business.Experience.ExperienceFactory.Search(Ropes.Services.Business.Search.SearchRequest)'.

I've recompiled a million times; emptied bin and obj folders, deleted and re-added references but to no avail.  My boss is coming down on me so if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated and I assure you karma will look kindly on you :)

Thank you

Comment: What was the exact changes you made? Perhaps that will help us to narrow down.

Comment: I changed the types of some properties.  I reverted the changes, but the same problem persists.  I had an int field and a double field and i changed them to int? and double? respectively.  Then I changed the both to strings.  Then I said screw it and changed them back because of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the offending .dll to the GAC.  Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Or, probably, remove the already existing, old, dll from the GAC?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm first check the definitions (public, private, protected etc), then check the Build order. If everything is ok, try to open new solution, add same references to new solution and try to build - use function. If the problem keeps occur, then you have a problem :) letme search a bit :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and am having the same problem.  Not sure if this is related, but I'm also getting this message when trying to step through the service call:

Comment: Unable to automatically step into the server.  The debugger failed to stop in the server process.  Debugging is enabled in my web.config.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'Check the build order'

Comment: I mean, when you make some changes in method, the changes wont appear instantly. You need to Build project which you made changes, then run the project. Project Build Order manages this :)